# What is the best known lower bound on $R(24,24)$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I have shown that the diagonal Ramsey number $R(24,24)$ is at least 27812.  How does this compare to the best known bound?

Comment: Are you familiar with the lower bound [due to P. Erdős](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Bounds_for_Ramsey_numbers#Lower_bound)?

Comment: Yes, I believe that gives 27595.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [a paper written in Chinese](http://www.xueshu.com/wzxyxb/201202/6809202.html) which I cannot read but which claims to show that $R(23,23) > 129629$ using the Paley graph construction.

This is not too implausible. The same construction [was used in 2002](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.9888&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to prove that $R(19, 19) > 17885$, which far outstrips the probabilistic bound of $R(19, 19) > 3923$. So even though I cannot read the Chinese paper, I believe that the calculations should be possible by now, and could well give a result that large.

Comment: Just now I noticed that depending on where you look in the paper, the bound is either $129629$ or $29629$, so I'm not sure what to think.